How to not show ChewieController blinking when widget is rebuilt?
I'm using ChewieController for video player. For me, when an error is shown, setState is triggered to re-initialize _chewieController, but when setState is called, the controller blinks (progress bar video). I need to get rid of blinking controls when setState is triggered, how can I do this?
_chewieController = ChewieController(
        videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
        autoInitialize: true,
        allowFullScreen: true,
        aspectRatio: widget.videoContent.isVertical ? 0.5 : 16 / 9,
        looping: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        showControlsOnInitialize: false,
        errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {    
          if (errorMessage == "Failed to load video: Operation Stopped" ||
              errorMessage == "Failed to load video: unknown error" &&
                  numberTryInit <= maxNumberTryInit) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {}));

            numberTryInit = numberTryInit + 1;
            return const SizedBox.shrink();
          }

          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Center(
              child: CustomText.title(
                text: "error_load_video".tr(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        showOptions: false,
        cupertinoProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
          handleColor: Colors.white,
          playedColor: AppProperties.accentColor,
          bufferedColor: const Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.8),
        ),
        materialProgressColors: ChewieProgressColors(
          handleColor: Colors.white,
          playedColor: AppProperties.accentColor,
          bufferedColor: const Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.8),
        ),
        placeholder: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );




return SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
          future: _initVideoController(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Stack(children: [
                Chewie(
                  controller: _chewieController,
                ),
                if (snapshot.data != null && !snapshot.data!)
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: CustomText.title(
                        text: "error_load_video".tr(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
              ]);
            }


future: _initVideoController() will recall the API every-time(build) call the setState.
You can use a state variable for the future.
late Future future =  _initVideoController();  // on state class 
....
///inside build method
return SafeArea(
  child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
    future: future,

And to reload
 errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {    
   if (...apiReloadContition) {
        setState(() {
           future =  _initVideoController();
         }));
        numberTryInit = numberTryInit + 1;
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
   }


I need when setState(() {} is called, then call the _initVideoController method again, in your case the _initVideoController method is called only once and if there is an error, the controller will not start again

you can reassign the future to rebuild/recall the api again, and replace  the final with Future

Can you please show me an example because I don’t really understand how to do this?
